# Statistical test for testing equal proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, proportion, discrete-data

I have a questionnaire item (N=6572) for which:

5064 (77.1%) subjects **responded** to the question, and

1508 (22.9%) subjects **did not respond** to the question.

What statistical test should i use to test if the **proportion of subjects who responded = proportion of subjects who did not respond?**

I am thinking one sample z test for proportions. Please advise.

Comment: There are no responses from those who did not respond, so your question, as worded, makes no sense. Do you mean "is the proportion of people who answered = to that that did not answer?" (not sure why you would want to know) or is it something else?

Comment: Yes you can say that my question is to test, if the proportion of people who answered = to that that did not answer?

Comment: You can use a one-way chi-square test, among other things

Comment: Yes, you could use a z-test for proportions (a one-sample test of whether the proportion responding is 0.5), but I am not sure why those two proportions being equal (proportion responding being 0.5) would be an interesting thing to test against (why on earth would they ever be suspected to be likely to be equal?), but in any case you can instantly see the p-value is far smaller than any typical significance level (consider the 95% margin of error on a proportion at n=1000 is somewhere around 0.03).

Comment: Thanks Glen ! I agree with you. Although 1 sample z test for proportions can be conducted it is difficult to justify this test

Answer (score 2):

I think you really want to test $H_0: p=.5$, where $p$ is the proportion of people answering. An easy way to get your hands on that problem is to get the confidence interval for the proportion estimate of people answering.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

For your problem the 99.9% CI is [.753,.788], so you can reject the null hypothesis. There are clearly more people responding to the question than not responding.